# Never want to hide tooltip on highcharts

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

I am using HighCharts in my ASP.Net MVC application using JQuery.

I have managed to show a tooltip with crosshair vertical bar on mouse move. However, I do not want to hide this toolop + bar even if user moves the mouse out of chart. Is there any option available in Highcharts to achieve this?

I searched forums but could not find any working example. One of those solutions is related to cloning tooltip on click event.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can [wrap](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) the `Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.hide` by an empty (no-op) function as follows

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'hide', function (defaultCallback) {
        /*
            ░░░░░▄▄▄▄▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▄▄▄▄▄▄░░░░░░░
            ░░░░░█░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▀▀▄░░░░
            ░░░░█░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒░░█░░░
            ░░░█░░░░░░▄██▀▄▄░░░░░▄▄▄░░░░█░░
            ░▄▀▒▄▄▄▒░█▀▀▀▀▄▄█░░░██▄▄█░░░░█░
            █░▒█▒▄░▀▄▄▄▀░░░░░░░░█░░░▒▒▒▒▒░█
            █░▒█░█▀▄▄░░░░░█▀░░░░▀▄░░▄▀▀▀▄▒█
            ░█░▀▄░█▄░█▀▄▄░▀░▀▀░▄▄▀░░░░█░░█░
            ░░█░░░▀▄▀█▄▄░█▀▀▀▄▄▄▄▀▀█▀██░█░░
            ░░░█░░░░██░░▀█▄▄▄█▄▄█▄████░█░░░
            ░░░░█░░░░▀▀▄░█░░░█░█▀██████░█░░
            ░░░░░▀▄░░░░░▀▀▄▄▄█▄█▄█▄█▄▀░░█░░
            ░░░░░░░▀▄▄░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░▒░░░█░
            ░░░░░░░░░░▀▀▄▄░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░█░
            ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▀▄▄▄▄▄░░░░░░░░█░░
            */
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

[Highcharts/Highstock tooltip always visible @ JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/3dEJc/)

For the minimalists,

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'hide', function () {});
}(Highcharts));
```

does the job too ;)

Read More @ [Customizing Highcharts - Tooltip Visibility](http://ahumbleopinion.com/customizing-highcharts-tooltip-visibility/)

Comment: Nice one. It's working! Now it is showing the tooltip on mouse moving out of graph. But the bar is hiding. Any simillar code for bar? My guess - chart.tooltip.crosshair.hide = ...... ?

Comment: Got it.. it is 
chart.tooltip.hideCrosshairs
=function(){};

Comment: @ the next one who upvotes the answer, could you please tell me the source from where this answer is drawing so much attention? Not complaining, just curious :)

Comment: @JugalThakkar reddit. http://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/20axyh/we_have_a_wise_guyhere/

Comment: Nice one @JugalThakkar

Comment: ahh snap forgot to upvote your answer,
xpsdeset. and it was usefull.